# Bohr Effect - related to H+ only?

Tags: biochemistry

Would I be correct in saying that the Bohr effect is ONLY related to the concentration of [H+] in the tissues.

Obviously the concentration of carbon-dioxide can contribute to this concentration by producing protons (through carbonic anhydrase) but it isn't directly involved in the effect?

Comment: I thin you may read this it explains...[Bohr effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_effect)